# 1136: Incorrect number of arguments. Expected 0

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I ask this question time and time again and havnt got an answer. Its driving me crazy evertytime I get it. Sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesnt. When I pass a object through the constructor, it gives me the error message. So I always got to make a second method to get it to work. Here is my code if anyone can please help me

```
var ds = new desertStorm(ship);
```

Above is the object i call and below is the class.

```
package com.objects{

    import flash.display.MovieClip

    public class desertStorm extends Stinger {

        private var turret1:Torret;
        private var swap:Boolean = false;
        private var target:Avatar;
        public function desertStorm(target:Object):void
        {
            this.target = target;
            health = 2;
            turret1 = new Torret();
            eApi.addGameChild(turret1);
        }

        override public function updateObject():void
        {
            if(!swap)
            {
                eApi.swapGameChildren(this, turret1);
                swap = true;
            }
            y += cspeed;
            turret1.x = x;
            turret1.y = (y + 40);
        }
    }
}
```

if anyone can help me out that would be great

Comment: What's the declaration of `eApi.addGameChild`?

Comment: The issue isnt with eApi. Ive done some trouble shooting and the error goes away if I remove the ship variable from the desert storm parameter. Now as of right now, flash says it expects 0 parameters. so If I remove ship from the parameter and keep  public function desertStorm(target:Object):void. this is the error i get.... '1203: No default constructor found in base class com.objects:desertStorm.' Im not sure what that means but it sounds like I dont have a constructor when I do

Answer (score 1):

I was encountering the same error.  In my scenario I had a class in a subfolder named buttons.  I modified the package statement accordingly (to include the folder path) and used the import statement correctly in the class that was instantiating the class in the buttons folder.  The class that was in the buttons folder was attached to a movieclip in the library of the fla.

That was my problem.  For the movieclip in the library (of the fla) I had to modify the Symbol Properties > Class name box to include the folder path.

My class is named MakeButton.as and is in a folder named buttons. I consequently modified the symbol in the library as follows:  buttons.MakeButton,  where buttons is the subfolder MakeButton.as is in. The fla, document class, and other classes are in the folder above the buttons folder.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing seems to be on this line:

```
eApi.addGameChild(turret1);
```

I would look into the `eApi` object and see if `addGameChild` accepts any parameters.

Comment: Its not. if I remove 'ship' from the desertStorm() param, and remove it from the constructors param, the error goes away

Comment: Ive had this issue countless times before and I dont know if I got a bad copy or what

Comment: Ive had these issues before and I usually just create another method to take in those parameters, but now its bugging me and I would rather do it the correct way

Comment: Have you tried explicitly calling the super() constructor? (how many arguments does the constructor for Stinger have?)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line to your constructor:

`super();`

This will explicitly call the constructor of the base class and pass it zero arguments. It could be that if the base class's constructor is not called explicitly in this fashion it is called with the same arguments as the child class's constructor.

This is just a hunch, though; I can't remember the rules for constructors in ActionScript 3.

EDIT: It seems Gabriel McAdams came up with this before me, but I didn't see his comment in time.

Answer (score 0):

## Updated Answer:#

[This listing of compiler errors](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/compilerErrors.html) says:

> You must explicitly call the constructor of the base class with a super() statement if it has 1 or more required arguments.

Given your error (`1203: No default constructor found in base class com.objects:desertStorm.`), it looks like you are extending `desertStorm` somewhere and need to call the `super()` function with the appropriate parameter.

This simple example given below will fail with this compiler error:
`1203: No default constructor found in base class Class1.`

Indicating that the issue is in the class that extends `Class1`.

So find whereever you're extending `desertStorm` and call the correct super-constructor.

#### Example:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Class1 extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Class1(property:String)
        {
            super();
        }
    }
}

package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Class2 extends Class1
    {
        public function Class2()
        {
            // You need to call the super constructor here.
            // super("Work!");
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Original Answer:

> If I remove ship from the parameter and keep public function 
>   desertStorm(target:Object):void. this is the error i get....
>   '1203: No default constructor found in base class com.objects:desertStorm.'
>   Im not sure what that means but it sounds like I dont have a constructor when I do

Whilst you do have a constructor, you don't have a **default** constructor.

If you have created any instances of `desertStorm` by dragging them from the library to the stage then you must define a default constructor, such as:

```
public function desertStorm():void
{
    super();

    // Do simple initialisation behaviour here.
}
```

This is because Flash doesn't know how to instantiate your class if it has a custom constructor - how can it?

Instead, move the other behaviour into an initialisation function that knows all about your `target` object:

```
public function init(target:Object)
{
    this.target = target;
    health = 2;
    turret1 = new Torret();
    eApi.addGameChild(turret1);
}
```

Then you can just instantiate it like this:

```
var ds = new desertStorm();
ds.init(ship);

// Do whatever else you need to do with your desertStorm object, e.g.:
addChild(ds);
```

Comment: I havnt dragged any items from the library to the stage. all ive done and created movieclips, and linked them to the custom classes I created for them.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that if you accidentially put the class file and the fla-file in different folders, a 1136 error will be shown. Make sure that the class file is found by the fla-file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simple version of some of the existing responses:

**Make sure the linkage name / Class path in Symbol Properties contains the full package path of your class.**

For instance, if your package is com.company.project, and your class is MyClass, the string in the Class box in Symbol Properties must read:

```
com.company.project.MyClass
```

If you only have MyClass in that box, Flash creates a class definition for you that is not the one you have coded, which is why is doesn't have constructor parameters and gives you the "Expected 0" error.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out that the issue is with custom classes that are attached to movieclips in the library. For some reason you cant pass arguements to classes that have movieclips from the library attached. Dont believe me ? try it out!!!

And ummm, for whoever gave me a negative, try this out

```
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Main():void
        {
            var test:Block = new Block("test");
        }
    }
}
```

add the following

```
package com {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Block extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Block(test:String):void
        {
            trace(test);
        }
    }
}
```

Then create a block movieclip and attach it to Block. make sure put Block into the com folder. When doing so you get the following

```
1136: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected 0.
```

If you put Block into the root folder with the fla file, it should work fine.